# Inject A C# Function to all of ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have a Asp.net MVC Project that it has over 1000 ActionResult and I need to add all of them a C# Function for check value of Session.
So What is your offer to do this?
These two following lines has some example of my Controller and ActionResult :

```
    public partial class CRMController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult OrganizationCategory()
       {
        //I want add a C# function here 
       }
    }
    public partial class BaseInfoController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult Lead()
       {
         //I Want Add a C# Function here
       }
     }
```

Comment: check my answer and tell me if something is not understandable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ActionFilters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) for this.

> The base ActionFilterAttribute class has the following methods that
>   you can override:
>
> OnActionExecuting – This method is called before a controller action
>   is executed. OnActionExecuted – This method is called after a
>   controller action is executed. OnResultExecuting – This method is
>   called before a controller action result is executed. OnResultExecuted
>   – This method is called after a controller action result is executed.

Here full code example !

```
 public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute

 {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }

      public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }

      public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnResultExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }

      public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnResultExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }

      private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
      {
           var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
           var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
           var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", methodName, controllerName, actionName);
           Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
      }
 }

 [LogActionFilter]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           return View();
      }

      public ActionResult About()
      {

           return View();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please create a action filter attribute, in that check sessions. Then create a Base Controller, then apply this attribute in that controller.  Then inherit this base controller with your business controllers.

```
public class MySessionCheckFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {

       //Check Session Method()
       //if(SessionNotAvaliable)
       //{
       //    throw new businessException;
       //}

       base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}

[MySessionCheckFilterAttribute]
public class BaseController:Controller
{

}

public class YourController_One: BaseController
{
    //Do anything
}

public class YourController_Two : BaseController
{
    //Do anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is on checking the Session, i thought it could relates to an authorization process. If so, you can try with [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Example: Checking the `Session["username"]` on every Function that tagged with `[AuthorizeAttribute]`:

```
public class SessionAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public SessionAuthAttribute() { }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            //base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            var userID = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["username"];
            if (userID == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home");
            }
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "Home",
                        action = "Index"
                    })
                    );
        }
    }
```

In Controller:

```
[SessionAuthAttribute] //Applied for whole Controller
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
      [SessionAuthAttribute] //Applied for 1 function
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           return View();
      }

      public ActionResult About()
      {

           return View();
      }
 }
```

**EDIT:** You can create this class in folder Attribute of your MVC Project